# How do I put a div on another div when using css?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm quite new to css and JQuery, and I'm quite confused by this problem. My code is very short as below:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".square-2").hide();
    $(".square-3").hide();

    $("#btn-1").click(function(){
        $(".square-2").fadeOut(); $(".square-3").fadeOut(); $(".square-1").fadeIn();
    });
    $("#btn-2").click(function(){
        $(".square-1").fadeOut(); $(".square-3").fadeOut(); $(".square-2").fadeIn();
    });
    $("#btn-3").click(function(){
        $(".square-1").fadeOut(); $(".square-2").fadeOut(); $(".square-3").fadeIn();
    });
});</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="square" class="square-1"></div>
    <div id="square" class="square-2"></div>
    <div id="square" class="square-3"></div>
</div>
<center><button id="btn-1">square-1</button><button id="btn-2">square-2</button><button id="btn-3">square-3</button></center>
</body>
```

And the corresponding css file is as below:

```
#container{
    width:300px;    
    margin:auto auto;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid;
}

#square{
    position:relative;
    margin:auto auto;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}

.square-1{
    background:#CC66CC;
}
.square-2{
    background:#FFFF00;
}
.square-3{
    background:#66FF00;
}
```

All I have is 3 squares of the same size, and I'd like to put them all at the same place. I want the corresponding square to fade in and the other 2 to fade out when I click each button. How should I make use of the *div id* and *class* to realize the effect?

P.S.: I heard that using more than one id with the same name in the same html is not a good habit, e.g. the "square" here. So how should I address this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: For the naming problem, the solution would be to use class="square square1" and style with .square and .square1

Answer (score 1):

First: `id` is an attribute with unique values; you just can't have more than one `id="square"` in your HTML. That is not even "not a good habit" but forbidden by the HTML standard.

Second: you should position the "squares" absolutely; the parent element (`#container`) should have a `position: relative;`. The relative positions refer to the element just before the current one – which is `.square-2` in the case of `square-3`.

Third: if your "squares" don't have content, there is no need to fade them in and out – just change the background color.

Answer (score 0):

You have a good start and just have a couple things that need to be cleaned up.

1. As @feeela mentioned, you need to have unique Id attributes. It looks like you just have the class and id trans-versed
2. Setup you css class's thinking of inheritance.
3. You're JavaScript code needs some work so you're not making multiple calls think about hooking on to all the buttons and fading the images accordingly.

**CSS**

```
.square {
    position:relative;
    margin:auto auto;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
.square.one{
    background:#CC66CC;
}
.square.two{
    background:#FFFF00;
}
.square.three{
    background:#66FF00;
}
```

**HTML**
Notice the use of the [data attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_object_data.asp)

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="square1" class="square one">Square One</div>
    <div id="square2" class="square two">Square Two</div>
    <div id="square3" class="square three">Square Three</div>
</div>
<div id="buttons">
    <button id="btn-1" data-linkedto="square1">square-1</button><button id="btn-2" data-linkedto="square2">square-2</button><button id="btn-3" data-linkedto="square3">square-3</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript** 
This is the best solution as it could use some touch ups, but it should get you thinking in the right direction.

```
$("button", "#buttons").click(function () {
    var $me = $(this);
    var linkedTo = $me.data('linkedto');
    $("#container").children().fadeOut("fast");
    $("#" + linkedTo, "#container").fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: `position:relative;` on the `.square` will cause a flicker in the moment of fading in/out because for a short time two squares are visible and will get positioned one below the other.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DKDKE/3/) for the code I have working.

I changed your styles so that there is a square class that defines the size. I then made a div called squareContainer that I use to position the boxes in the center. This is needed because the absolutely positioned colored boxes ignore margin. The squareContainer helps to define their shape and space so that it doesn't mess up the rest of the layout.

Hope that helps.